# Wordpress customization on custom post

Tags: wordpress, customization

Is there any option? So I can add an option on any custom post via WordPress customization? Actually, I added a custom post on my WordPress theme. Here user needs to add font awesome icon. But I do not want to add option tree metabox and not a custom field. A user will not remember different custom field. So Is there any option?

Answer (score 1):

At some level you are going to end up adding something like a custom field to your post.  However, I agree that the user interface for custom fields is clunky and non-intuitive.  I agree with you that making an end-user use that would be a bad idea.

Instead, I would recommend using the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.  It enables you to add meta-data to posts, pages and/or custom post types.  It's extremely flexible, intuitively designed and well-documented.

ACF permits you to place your custom field in a variety of places on the Add Post (or custom post) page:  just below the visual editor window, on the right with the meta-boxes, or in a meta-box.

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/